# TestNG or Spring Test framework?

Tags: spring, testng

I have used TestNG+Rest Assured for rest api service testing(application is written based on Spring framework) and just want to know if it is better to use Spring test framework alone or integration TestNG+Spring test.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **combination** of both.

TestNG will act as **full featured test framework** and Spring Test framework to **mock spring beans** (In other words, to get the out of the box spring support).